# Сортировка интервалов

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть модель интервала с полями `begin` и `end`, оба поля могут быть `None`. Нужно в классе мета модели прописать ordering, чтобы сортировать эти интервалы по возрастанию.

Comment: По возрастанию чего?

Comment: @Igor В этом и проблема. Нельзя же просто взять и отсортировать по возрастанию begin или end. И я не могу придумать как вообще можно отсортировать интервал.

Comment: Это Вы должны определить условие сортировки, исходя из смысла Вашей задачи и смысла этих интервалов. По началу, или по длине, или по началу и длине, или как-то еще.